# How to copy BGE logic from one object to another using script?

Tags: python, game-engine

How to copy BGE logic from one object to another using script?

I use the following code (coppied from an addon) to create a duplicate of an object ...

```
def copyObject(scene, name, copyobj, location ):

  # Create new mesh
  mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)

  # Create a new object.
  ob_new = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
  ob_new.data = copyobj.data.copy()
  ob_new.scale = copyobj.scale
  ob_new.location = location
  scene.objects.link(ob_new)

  return ob_new
```

But this does not copy the game logic from the original object.

Thanks!

Comment: [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23383/935) will show the python paths of the logic bricks data. I don't think you can do a `copy()` but you can step through the properties of each brick and recreate them.

Comment: thx sambler. selecting the object and using bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move seems to be working. I'll post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following workaround of selecting the object and using bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move works for my case ...

```
def copyObject( scene, name, copyobj, loc ):
  bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
  copyobj.select = True
  l = (loc[0] - copyobj.location[0],loc[1] - copyobj.location[1],loc[2] - copyobj.location[2])
  bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move( TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":l} )
  obj = scene.objects[0]
  obj.name = name
  return obj
```

Answer (score 6):

To copy game logic from one object to one or many others:

Select the other object (or multiples using shift) first (object you would like to copy game logic nodes **to**)

Select the object you want to copy from (using shift to select)

Click Object->Game->Copy Logic Bricks

( or script as bpy.ops.object.logic_bricks_copy() )

Can be done for Properties as well as Physics properties.

Is this the type of copy you are looking for?

Comment: I was looking for copying the whole deal (as when you do with shift-D). But this script would be handy if I wanted to copy just the logic bricks. thx!